# Switching off debug prints

Tags: python

Sometimes I have a lot of prints scattered around function to print debug output.
To switch this debug outputs I came up with this:

```
def f(debug=False): 
    print = __builtins__.print if debug else lambda *p: None
```

Or if I need to print something apart from debug message, I create `dprint` function for debug messages.

The problem is, when `debug=False`, this `print` statements slow down the code considerably, because `lambda *p: None` is still called, and function invocation are known to be slow.

So, my question is: Is there any better way to efficiently disable all these debug prints for them not to affect code performance?

---

All the answers are regarding my not using `logging` module. This is a good to notice, but this **doesn't answer the question** how to avoid function invocations that slow down the code considerably - in my case 25 times (if it's possible (for example by tinkering with function code object to through away all the lines with `print` statements or somehow else)). What these answers suggest is replacing `print` with `logging.debug`, which should be even slower. And this question is about getting rid of those function calls completely.

I tried using `logging` instead of `lambda *p: None`, and no surprise, code became even slower.

---

Maybe someone would like to see the code where those prints caused 25 slowdown: http://ideone.com/n5PGu

And I don't have anything against `logging` module. I think it's a good practice to always stick to robust solutions without some [*hacks*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12223240/862380). But I thinks there is nothing criminal if I used those *hacks* in 20-line one-time code snippet.

---

Not as a restriction, but as a suggestion, maybe it's possible to delete some lines (e.g. starting with `print`) from function source code and recompile it? I laid out this approach in the answer below. Though I would like to see some comments on that solution, I welcome other approaches to solving this problem.

Comment: Even though i discurage the use of your function: If you use `lambda`, there will be a new function object everytime it is called. So if you put in an empty function instead, it wouldn't slow down your code that much.

Comment: @twall It's called only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ned Batchelder** wrote in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229424/replacing-parts-of-the-function-code-on-the-fly#comment16388151_12229424):

> I suspect the slow down is in the calculation of the arguments to
>   your debug function. You should be looking for ways to avoid those
>   calculations. Preprocessing Python is just a distraction.

And he is right as slowdown is actually caused by formatting string with `format` method which happens regardless if the resulting string will be logged or not.

So, string formatting should be deferred and dismissed if no logging will occur. This may be achieved by refactoring `dprint` function or using `log.debug` in the following way:

```
log.debug('formatted message: %s', interpolated_value)
```

If message won't be logged, it won't be formatted, unlike `print`, where it's always formatted regardless of if it'll be logged or discarded.

The solution on `log.debug`'s postponed formatting gave **Martijn Pieters** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229424/replacing-parts-of-the-function-code-on-the-fly/12229535#comment16387853_12229535).

Answer (score 5):

You should use the `logging` module instead. See http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Then you can set the log level depending on your needs, and create multiple logger objects, that log about different subjects.

```
import logging
#set your log level
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This is a log message')
```

---

In your case: you could simply replace your print statement with a log statement, e.g.:

```
import logging
print = __builtins__.print if debug else logging.debug
```

now the function will only be print anything if you set the logging level to debug

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

But as a plus, you can use all other logging features on top! `logging.error('error!')`

Comment: Will that `logging.debug` be faster than `lambda *b: None`?

Comment: no probably not. but it will make your code more maintainable.

Comment: Note that the `.debug()` (and related methods) supported deferred string formatting; `.debug(msg, *args, **kw)` will be translated to `msg % args` or `msg % kw`, depending on what was passed in, if the message is actually going to be logged.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is right: logging will be faster because you are only calling it, you aren't computing messages and then calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to dynamically edit code of `f` and delete all `drpint` calls. But this solution is highly [unrecommended to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238511/preprocessing-function-text-in-runtime-bofore-compilation#comment16403281_12238725):

> You are correct, you should never resort to this, there are so many
>   ways it can go wrong. First, Python is not a language designed for
>   source-level transformations, and it's hard to write it a transformer
>   such as comment_1 without gratuitously breaking valid code. Second,
>   this hack would break in all kinds of circumstances - for example,
>   when defining methods, when defining nested functions, when used in
>   Cython, when inspect.getsource fails for whatever reason. Python is
>   dynamic enough that you really don't need this kind of hack to
>   customize its behavior.

Here is the code of this approach, for those who like to get acquainted with it:

```
from __future__ import print_function

DEBUG = False

def dprint(*args,**kwargs):
    '''Debug print'''
    print(*args,**kwargs)

_blocked = False
def nodebug(name='dprint'):
    '''Decorator to remove all functions with name 'name' being a separate expressions'''
    def helper(f):      
        global _blocked
        if _blocked:
            return f

        import inspect, ast, sys

        source = inspect.getsource(f)        
        a = ast.parse(source) #get ast tree of f

        class Transformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
            '''Will delete all expressions containing 'name' functions at the top level'''
            def visit_Expr(self, node): #visit all expressions
                try:
                    if node.value.func.id == name: #if expression consists of function with name a
                        return None #delete it
                except(ValueError):
                    pass
                return node #return node unchanged
        transformer = Transformer()
        a_new = transformer.visit(a)
        f_new_compiled = compile(a_new,'<string>','exec')

        env = sys.modules[f.__module__].__dict__
        _blocked = True
        try:
            exec(f_new_compiled,env)
        finally:
            _blocked = False
        return env[f.__name__]         
    return helper


@nodebug('dprint')        
def f():
    dprint('f() started')
    print('Important output')
    dprint('f() ended')
    print('Important output2')


f()
```

More information: [Replacing parts of the function code on-the-fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229424/replacing-parts-of-the-function-code-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 0):

As a hack, yes, that works. (And there is no chance in hell those lambda no-ops are your app's bottleneck.)

However, you really should be doing logging properly by using the `logging` module.

See http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial for a basic example of how this should be done.

Comment: Those `print`s slowed down my code 25 times! (that function was a number-crunching algorithm, so such things may happen).

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `logging` module. But I think that in code snippets 20 lines long made just for myself using `logging` would be an overkill.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I'm content with 25 times slowdown! But I made this question out of curiosity: maybe there is technique how I can disable all those `print`s invocations.

Comment: @ovgolovin if your scripts are only 20 lines long, I would probably use the 'comment out the print statements' technique

Comment: @Matt Yeah. I use nearly the same technique. I just made 2 versions of the code: one with prints and another without (because those prints clutter the code and make it completely unreadable). Downside is that 2 separate functions have to be maintained in sync. Starting this question on StackOverflow I expected that maybe there is a standard technique to get rid of some lines in code objects somehow by using `func.__code__`

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module of Python, it's very practical and you can change the log level of your application. Example:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.debug('Test.')
DEBUG:root:Test.
```